# Pass an argument to a controller on button click event

Tags: javascript, button

I added a button to my view as below. After I click that button a popup window opens.

I want to pass an argument to my controller at the button click event.

```
<div style="float: right;">
  <a id="btn-language-content" class="k-button custombtn lightblue k-grid-add btn-info" href="">
    <span class='metiralclass material-icons md-18 md-dark'>add_circle</span>
    <span class='buttontext'> @Resource.btnAdd</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

My button click event is:

```
$('body').on('click', '#btn-language-content', function () {
  var addWin = $("#winLanguageContent").data("kendoWindow");
  addWin.open();
  addWin.center();       
  addWin.refresh({
    url: '@Url.Action("_LanguageEditor", "HelpSystem", new { area = "HelpSystem" 
  })',
});
```

Comment: seems incomplete.. add more details or jsfiddle here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass data to javascript this way you need to add an HTML data attribute to your button like this:

```
<a id="btn-language-content" class="k-button custombtn lightblue k-grid-add btn-info" href="" data-kendo-window="value"></a>
```